# How to target a specific tag to be affected by a specific CSS file

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this following HTML5 code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>AUMC-Student Portal</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css2/paper.css" rel="stylesheet" media = "screen">
         <link href="css2/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media = "screen">



        <style>
        form{
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            vertical-align: middle;
            padding-top: 15%;
        }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id = "AllControls" class="Controls">
            <fieldset id = "fomrControl" class = "Inputs">
                <br>
                <input type = "text" class = "form-control" placeholder="Username" />
                <br>
                <input type = "password" class = "form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                <br>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Forgot</button>   
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button> 
                <br>
            <fieldset/>
        <form/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am linking two CSS file one is **`paper.css`** and other is **`bootstrap.css`**. Here's what when I apply them individually commenting the other out.[image]

Now I want my input fields to have the look using **`bootstrap.css`** and buttons to have the look using **`paper.css`**. but when I include both CSS files it gives me an amalgam I don't want as both are affecting the input fields and the buttons.I tried changing class names in the CSS files and it worked to some extent but its painful that way to find every single line that could affect your element.Also,I know that @import in scoped styles is deprecated.

So,

**Is there any way to target my input fields and buttons to use only one of these CSS files without altering the CSS files themselves ?**

Comment: You can define your own class and then apply it.  The behavior you are seeing is how style sheets are intended to behave.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Can you explain a bit on how to do that ? Does that include changing the class name of the tag or in the CSS file or am I wrong about what you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a custom class for the buttons and then copying the css code for buttons from the paper.css file and applying it to the custom class.

Comment: I see, that is nice but in the CSS files there are multiple section which are responsible for the complete working of the element such as in the following link http://bootswatch.com/paper/bootstrap.css how am I suppose to find all the line of codes affecting the button tag. This is very time consuming. Is this really the only way ?